# How to stick image to div block in CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image

I'm trying to stick an image to div block in CSS. I couldn't move 'image' using margin... What can I do?  Advice is appreciated. Thank you.

What I want to implement

[image]

```css
    .bottalk {
    background-color: white;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 280px; 
    border-radius: 1.5em;
    }

    .bottalk p {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    }

    .bot .bottalkwhite {
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    }

    .bottalk button {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: purple;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    border: none;
    margin-left: 50px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #666666;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="col-6 bot">
    <div class="bottalk">
    <p>Ready to get started?</p>
    <button>Let's talk</button>
    </div>
    <img src="./img/bottalk.png" alt="bottalk" class="bottalkwhite" />
    </div> </div>
```

Current view

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ignore the background color: I snipped it from the second image!

I have moved the position of the image inside the div with class `bottalk`, then I absolutely positioned the image, then all you need to do is to set the top and left position based on the image, (**`Cropped the image online so please ignore the quality of the output`**), So now you can position this anywhere. Also I have added `background-color:pink` to the `body` to show the image, please ignore this too.

So to summarize. I set the parent `div` element with class `bottalk` as `position:relative` and the child image with class `bottalkwhite` to `position:absolute` so that it can be positioned inside the parent. Position absolute will take the position relative to the immediate parent with `position:relative`, I hope I made my summary clear.

```css
body{
    background-color:pink;
}

.bottalk {
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 280px; 
    border-radius: 1.5em;
    }

    .bottalk p {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    }

    .bot .bottalkwhite {
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80%;
    left: -30px;
    }

    .bottalk button {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: purple;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    border: none;
    margin-left: 50px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #666666;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-6 bot">
    <div class="bottalk">
    <p>Ready to get started?</p>
    <button>Let's talk</button>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7i9bY.gif" alt="bottalk" class="bottalkwhite" />
    </div>
    </div> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `position: relative;` and adjust the values of the top and left properties， like the follow code：

```css
    .bottalk {
    position: relative;
    left: -5px;
    top: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 280px; 
    border-radius: 1.5em;
    }

    .bottalk p {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    }

    .bot .bottalkwhite {
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    }

    .bottalk button {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: purple;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    border: none;
    margin-left: 50px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #666666;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="col-6 bot">
    <div class="bottalk">
    <p>Ready to get started?</p>
    <button>Let's talk</button>
    </div>
    <img src="./img/bottalk.png" alt="bottalk" class="bottalkwhite" />
    </div> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to put a image into a exact position relative to its ancestor, you can set position property to absolute then using left-right-top-bottom properties, you can determine its exact position. like this:

```
.bottalkwhite{
    position: absolute;
    left: 250px;
    top: 0px;
    }
```

though in such a particular css rule definition using id selector instead of class selector sounds more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:relative` on the wrapper element of the image and position the image via `position: absolute`, `left: 0` and `bottom: 0` in the bottom-left corner. Then adjust it's position via `transform: translate`, to get the desired effect.

Note: I moved  the image into the `div.botttalk` container to position it relative to its parent.

Like this:

```css
body {
  background: #715886;
  font-family: Open Sans, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.bottalk {
  background-color: white;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 100px; 
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 24px 16px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #715886;
}

.bottalk .bottalkwhite {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 40px;
  color: white;
  transform: translate(-100%, 100%) translate(16px, -16px);
}

.bottalk h4 {
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0 0 24px 0;
}

.bottalk button {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #715886;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fbcb33;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 32px;
  border: none;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #666666;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-6 bot">
  <div class="bottalk">
    <h4>Ready to get started?</h4>
    <button>Let's talk</button>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/oeUdlld.png" alt="bottalk" class="bottalkwhite" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does this do? How does it answer the question? Don't just vomit markup.

Comment: I was writing an explanation.